# Jenkins-Display a table in console output

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How to display a table in Jenkins console output?
i.e. 
Name Age
ABC  10

How do i display this content in tabular format in Jenkins output?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display in a tabular format in Jenkins console just by Groovy script. The length of the value in each column is not fixed. Even if it is fixed, it will be a real pain to align all columns.

Take a look at this, see if this helps:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin

I do not know your requirement but I suggest you to rather create an html table using Groovy script.